# Вывод массива чисел, сумма которых равна определённому значению

Tags: javascript

Необходимо ввести число в поле `input`. На выходе, при нажатии кнопки, нужно получить массив чисел (от 1 до введенного числа), сумма цифр которых кратна 13.

Все перепроверил  несколько раз. Но, при нажатии на кнопку, страница просто виснет. Подскажите где ошибка?

```js
var insert = document.querySelector("input");
var output = document.querySelector("textarea");
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", fanc);

function getDigitsSum(data) {
  var a = String(data).split("");
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(a[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

function check(result) {
  return result === 13;
}

function getYears(number) {
  var array = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    if (check(getDigitsSum(i))) {
      array.push(i);
    }
  }
  return array;
}

function fanc() {
  output.value = getYears(insert.value).join(", ")
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" autofocus> <br>
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
  <button>Get array</button>
  <button>Get array</button>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Задание до идиотизма неопределённое... Если ориентироваться на то, что "от 1 до введенного числа" - это "все числа, без пропусков", то не факт, что сумма их цифр будет делиться на 13. А если это значит "только некоторые из этого диапазона", то для чисел 6 и более выводим (3,4,6), а для меньших - сообщение "невозможно".

Comment: Да, полагаю я недостаточно точно описал задачу.  Вводим число. Необходимо перебрать все числа от 1 до введенного числа и проверить сумму цифр каждого из этих чисел и если сумма цифр числа равна 13, то это число добавляем в массив. В результате на выходе должны получить массив включающий все  числа сумма цифр которых равна 13-ти. Надеюсь сейчас более понятно изложил?

Comment: То есть, каждое отдельное выводимое число должно иметь сумму цифр, делящуюся на 13?  Тогда сразу ошибка в `return result === 13;` - 13 не единственное число, делящееся на 13. А ещё - найдя первое число X с суммой цифр, делящейся на 13 (26, 39 и т.п.), можно далее тестировать только X+9*n. А найти первое число просто - напихиваем нужное количество девяток, потом сколько осталось, и переворачиваем. В общем, Вы не поработали головой, а сразу бросились писать код - напрасно. Он получился тупой, и потому очень медленный.

Comment: Я прошу прощения за тупость. В первый раз пишу на этом ресурсе и по этому блин выходит прямо огромным комом. В предыдущем комментарии я более детально описал проблему и указал там, что сумма цифр числа  должна  быть "равна 13-ти". В самом вопросе я действительно неверно указал "кратно 13". Поспешил.

Comment: Ну тогда ошибки нет - но остальное всё (тестировать только X+9*n, поиск первого из чисел, которое будет 49 - впрочем, можно и захардить) в силе.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Но подскажите, что именно тупого моем в коде. Я отработал каждый блок отдельно и все функции работаю без ошибок. Но когда соединяю все воедино, то даже при вводе числа 58, которое по идее должно давать всего два числа в новый массив и переборов не так много, страница все равно виснет. Я уже голову сломал пытаясь найти причину. Может вы сможете сказать что именно не так с этим кодом. Мне нужно понять чтобы не натыкаться на эти грабли в будущем.

Comment: *подскажите, что именно тупого моем в коде.* А что умного в переборе всех чисел подряд, если 90% из них гарантированно не подходят под условие?

Answer (score 0):

Советую повторить / подучить следующие темы:
var, let, const - чем отличаются, где используются.
Как именовать переменные и функции.

Еще я не совсем понял, зачем там сразу 2 кнопки, пустые атрибуты в textarea, и функция состоящая из одного условия.

```
const insert = document.querySelector("input");
const output = document.querySelector("textarea");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", handler);

function getDigitsSum(data) {
  const a = String(data).split("");
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(a[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

function getYears(number) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    if (getDigitsSum(i) === 13) {
      array.push(i);
    }
  }
  return array;
}

function handler() {
  output.value = getYears(+insert.value).join(", ")
}
```

PS. Я не вникал в задание, а только починил код.